# removing duplicate value based on condition

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I have data set as:

```
data <- read.table(text=
"id x1 x2 ind
1 2.5 11 0
1 4 13 0
1 4.6 14.5 0
2 0.5 10 0
2 2.5 12.5 0
2 2.5 12.5 1
2 4.6 16.5 0
3 0.5 11 0
3 4 14 0
3 4 14 1
4 0.5 11 0
4 3.5 15 0
4 5.5 16 0
4 5.5 16 1
4 10 15 0", header = TRUE)
```

and I would like to delete rows with same x1 value where ind=0 by id.
I like to get something like:

```
id x1 x2 ind
1 2.5 11 0
1 4 13 0
1 4.6 14.5 0
2 0.5 10 0
2 2.5 12.5 1
2 4.6 16.5 0
3 0.5 11 0
3 4 14 1
4 0.5 11 0
4 3.5 15 0
4 5.5 16 1
4 10 15 0
```

Comment: And... what did you try? What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: kk<-function(data){data[!duplicated(data$x1),]}
with(dataname, by(dataname, id, kk))  . THis code gave me the output but this code deleted the rows with ind=1. However, I want to delete rows with ind=0 for duplicated x1. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In base R,

```
subset(data, !(ind == 0 & ave(x1, id, x1, FUN = length) > 1))
```

To help understand, `ave` is what returns the frequencies per `(id, x1)` pairs:

```
with(data, ave(x1, id, x1, FUN = length))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
data[!duplicated(interaction(data[c("id", "x1")]), fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
library(data.table)
dataset <- data.table(dataset)

dataset[
   ,
   freq := .N,
   by = c("id","x1")
]

dataset[!(freq > 1 & ind ==0)]
```